# How to stop intervals inside Timeout delay on Event Broadcasts?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-broadcast

In my Angular 1.5, after user logs into their account, I have various directives that starts their interval inside a timeout. For example, I have this `UserEmailNotificationsCtrl` in one of the directives to check for new emails:

```
var intervalPromise;

$timeout(function () {
  stopInterval();
  intervalPromise = $interval(function() {
       checkNewEmail();
  }, 30000);
}, 20000);

$scope.$on('event:stop-intervals', function() {
      stopInterval();
});

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
   stopInterval();
});

function stopInterval() {
  $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
}
```

If incase the user logsout, I broadcast an event so the above interval is stopped in order to prevent 400 Bad Requests:

```
function logout() {
 $rootScope.$broadcast('event:stop-intervals');
}
```

The above works fine. However, this is the problem I am having:

If incase, the user logs out before the interval checks gets started, as it is wrapped inside a timeout to start after 20 seconds, the `event:stop-intervals` broadcast is missed. In these cases, the interval starts after the set timeout and does not know that the `event:stop-intervals` was fired to stop intervals before this.

My question is: **How can I check if the `event:stop-intervals` broadcast was fired before starting the interval in the directives? (or) How can the directive stop the interval from starting if `event:stop-intervals` was fired even before the interval check with timeout was triggered?**

Comment: Probably doing `var timeoutPromise = $timeout(function () { ... }, 20000);` and then calling `$timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise);` in your `stopInterval` method could do the trick for you. So it will cancel timeout and intervals will not be even set.

Comment: You are spot on. Thank you for that. I noticed that my http-auth-interceptor also broadcasts `$rootScope.$broadcast('event:stop-intervals');` during 400 bad requests but it appears the interval was still not getting cancelled. This is because the route had changed during logout and the scope is no longer active. So like u suggested, I added the `var timeoutPromise` and then added the cancel timeout inside the `$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {}` . So for my setup, adding the same inside the `stopInterval` method does the trick. Thank you so much. Yours is the correct answer for my issue.

Comment: Glad it helped you. Will add as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancelling `$timeout` promise using [`$timeout.cancel()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout#cancel) in your `stopInterval()` method will fix your issue so the intervals will not be even set:

```js
var intervalPromise;

var tiemoutPromise = $timeout(function () {
  stopInterval();
  intervalPromise = $interval(function() {
       checkNewEmail();
  }, 30000);
}, 20000);

$scope.$on('event:stop-intervals', function() {
  stopInterval();
});

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  stopInterval();
});

function stopInterval() {
  $timeout.cancel(tiemoutPromise);
  $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
}
```